# Pivot a datatable in .NET Code

Tags: vb.net, datatable, pivot

I have a stored procedure in SQL that returns the following schema:

```
ID  Category        AgeBucket   Cnt     Amount
28  Mack - Class 8  1To60         1       88000
28  Mack - Class 8  1To89         1       88000
28  Mack - Class 8  Over180      24     1067260.01
28  Mack - Class 8  Over359      24     1067260.01
28  Mack - Class 8  Over360      24     1067260.01
29  Volvo - Class 8 Over180      19      869100
29  Volvo - Class 8 Over359      19      869100
29  Volvo - Class 8 Over360      19      869100
30  Other - Class 8 Over180      13     232500.01
30  Other - Class 8 Over359      13     232500.01
30  Other - Class 8 Over360      13     232500.01
```

I want to pivot it in Vb.net (for some reasons) and the output datatable should look like this:

```
ID  Category SaleCategory   [1To60]  [1To89] [61To120] [90To179] [121To180] 
28     Mackclass8    N      88000   88000       0         0        0
29     Volvoclass8   N          0       0       0         0        869100
30     OtherClass8   N          0       0       0         0        232500.01
```

etc...
So, I have to pivot only the `AgeBucket` rows into different columns. Any suggestions?

Comment: That not a pivot, you want to decompose a column and summarize by it.  What value(s) are stored for AgeBucket?  Is it just text (ie `1To89`).  It also looks like they decompose differently or there is overlap between tiers

Comment: Age Bucket is all text.. there is a fixed list for Age Bucket...[1To60],[1To89],[61To120], [90To179],[121To180] , [180To269],[181To360],[270To359],Over360,Over359,[61To90],[91To120],[61To180],Over180